# Setting property of dictionary type works in constructor but not when using property default

Tags: c#

I have a class that has a property of type `Dictionary<object, Func<object, TreeNode>>`. I can happily set this property from the constructor (or by using an expression body), but not as a default value of the property (it doesn't change if the property is readonly, or have public get/set). This issue also occurs if the dictionary is instead stored in a field.

It comes up with an error saying *Cannot access non-static method* 'MethodName' *in static context*.

This is the code that fails:

```C#
public class TreeViewBuilder
{
    public Dictionary<Type, Func<object, TreeNode>> ObjectTreeNodeBuilder { get; set; }
        = new Dictionary<Type, Func<object, TreeNode>>
    {
        {typeof(Type1), t => BuildType1TreeNode((Type1) t)},
        {typeof(Type2), t => BuildType2TreeNode((Type2) t)},
    };

    public TreeNode BuildType1TreeNode(Type1 type1)
    {
        return new TreeNode { Tag = type1 };
    }

    public TreeNode BuildType2TreeNode(Type2 type2)
    {
        return new TreeNode { Tag = type2 };
    }
}
```

But this code is fine:

```C#
public class TreeViewBuilder
{
    public Dictionary<Type, Func<object, TreeNode>> ObjectTreeNodeBuilder { get; set; }

    public TreeViewBuilder()
    {
        ObjectTreeNodeBuilder = new Dictionary<Type, Func<object, TreeNode>>
        {
            {typeof(Type1), t => BuildType1TreeNode((Type1) t)},
            {typeof(Type2), t => BuildType2TreeNode((Type2) t)},
        };
    }

    public TreeNode BuildType1TreeNode(Type1 type1)
    {
        return new TreeNode { Tag = type1 };
    }

    public TreeNode BuildType2TreeNode(Type2 type2)
    {
        return new TreeNode { Tag = type2 };
    }
}
```

I'm guessing that the `ObjectTreeNodeBuilder` property is being initialised before the `TreeViewBuilder` object is fully instantiated/constructed, therefore the methods aren't yet known about; and this is why it complains that the methods should be static. Is this correct, or is something else going on under the hood?

Comment: _"I'm guessing that the ObjectTreeNodeBuilder property is being initialised before the TreeViewBuilder object is fully instantiated/constructed"_ -- yes. More generally, you cannot access anything that would involve `this` before the constructor has executed. See the marked duplicate for details.

Comment: @PeterDuniho Where do I see the marked duplicate?

Comment: Click on the link that appears just below the text reading _"This question already has an answer here:"_, found in the banner that now appears at the top of your question.

Comment: Ah, yep, had to refresh the page.

Answer (score -1):

The compiler is creating a static constructor to set the default value for the property. As the error message indicates, the non-static methods are not accessible from the static constructor.

Comment: Maybe edit your answer to include a relevant corrected section of the code? The more detail you give in your answers, the better they are.

Comment: This answer is incorrect. There is no static constructor involved here. It is a _static context_, i.e. a context where only static members are legal.